# Why is puppet trying to make changes to user's files using another user's credentials and failing?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

On some servers puppet tries to enact changes to a user's files and directories using the wrong user's credentials and fails.

I am using puppet on 8 servers, some with Ubuntu OS (puppet 6.0.4 on 18.04, puppet 5.5.8 on 16.04) and some with Debian 9 (puppet 5.5.8). On three of the Ubuntu servers (not on all of them) one with puppet 5.5.8 and two with 6.04, puppet does something strange:

When running `puppet agent --test --debug`, the output looks like this (pseudonymized, of course):

```
Notice: 
/Stage[main]/User/Ssh_authorized_key[user1@computer1]/ensure: 
removed
Info: Computing checksum on file /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys
Debug: Creating /home/user1/.ssh as user2
Error: /Stage[main]/User/Ssh_authorized_key[user1@computer1]: Could 
not evaluate: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/user1/.ssh
Notice: 
/Stage[main]/User/Ssh_authorized_key[user3@computer3]/ensure: 
removed
Debug: Creating /home/user1/.ssh as user2
Error: /Stage[main]/User/Ssh_authorized_key[user3@computer3]: Could 
not evaluate: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/user1/.ssh
```

Please note, that puppet agent is running as root and user1, user2 and user3 are normal users.

Puppet was installed from the official puppetlabs-repository, following the current documentation.

The thing that I noticed is that while in the puppet manifest the users are identified by and their groups are only referenced by their username which is identical on all servers (user1 is user1 on all servers), the uid and gid are not managed by puppet and do differ (user1 has uid 1001 on one server and 1003 on another). As fas as I know, puppet should not use the uid if it is not set in the manifest, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Further analysis shows that this only happens if `purge_ssh_keys` is set to "true" for user2 and/or user3 and the ssh-keys for users 2 and 3 are present in the authorized_keys of user1. 
According to the documentation puppet only looks in the .ssh/authorized_keys file in the user’s home directory when `purge_ssh_keys` is set to "true".

Comment: If you want anyone here to essay an answer then we will need a [mcve].  It seems that that will need to involve not just manifest code, but sufficient information about the initial state of the target machine to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My above comment was correct, I include this for others having the same problem:
It seems that contrary to the [puppet doumentation here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/user.html#user-attribute-purge_ssh_keys) `purge_ssh_keys` if set under "user1" does not only

> "... look for keys in the .ssh/authorized_keys file in the user’s home
>   directory. Purge any keys that aren’t managed as ssh_authorized_key
>   resources."

and removes all keys not set as "ssh_authorized_key" for "user1".

But also tries to remove any occurrence of the key set as "ssh_authorized_key" for "user1" in any other user's "authorized_keys"-file.

Comment: I verified this by manually removing the offending key of "user1" from the "authorized_keys"-file of "user2". A subsequent puppet run only reported the above error for the "authorized_keys"-file of "user3". After I manually removed the key from "user3"'s "authorized_keys"-file, a further puppet run completed without error.

Comment: Trying to reproduce this on a Virtual-Box Ubuntu 18.04 server, I was not able to reproduce  this strange behaviour. On that server it all worked as intended.